# Clicking on a badge you earned shows deleted questions with links that go to a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, deleted-questions

If you earned a badge on a deleted question, you click on that badge you earned (in my example, it was Nice Answer), you'll see the link to the deleted answer. Click that link and you'll get the **oops** page.

Test it on my Nice Answer badge [HERE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=184451) (the bottom one in that list is deleted).

> [image]

I guess the fixes would be either:

1) Don't show deleted questions on there at all (consistent with the rest of the site). 
2) Show it, but don't have it as a link, just maybe put **[deleted]** beside it, something like:

> [image: badge2]

**I'd go for number 1.**

Comment: NOOOOOO!!! Some of the greatest deleted questions can only be found via the badge links.

Comment: 10kers _can_ follow the link. I propose option C: it is only not a link for an under-10k user.

Comment: +1 only for option 2.  10k users can see deleted posts and the badge page is the best for finding good deleted stuff..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be available after the next deployment.

If the current user can see the post, then it is shown normally.

[image]

If the current user cannot see the post, then a placeholder text is displayed.

[image]

Comment: Can you leave the post Title in there? It would drive me crazy to see "you got a badge for something, but I'm not going to tell you what"